# PHP Script stopping without any error

Tags: php, curl, memory-leaks, cron, export-to-csv

For some reason i do not know why my script is stopping. It runs for about **20mins** and then it stops without retrieving all the records. Im sure something is causing it to stop, but i don't know what. if it were out of memory then i suppose that error message would be thrown, but its not. **This project is due next week**. We are running this script by a **cron job**. Please help!

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit','4G'); 

$Num = $_GET['Num'];
$Token = $_GET['Token'];


if(strlen($Num) > 0){
$j = $Num;

$j = 1;
}
else{

$j = 0;
}


$e = 0;
$k = 0;
$g = 1;
$x=0;
$json = '';
$EmailIDs = array();

$leads = new bList();
$leads->listId = 2867;
$AllLeads = array();
$AllLeads = $leads->fields;


if(strlen($Token) > 0){
$NextPage = $Token;
$leads->nextPageToken = $NextPage;

}


RUN();

function RUN(){
global $leads;
global $k;
global $json;
global $Next;



if($k == 0){
AreUnsubscribed($leads->getData());
$k = 1;
$Next = $json[nextPageToken];
$NextPage = $Next;
}

else{
AreUnsubscribed($leads->getData());
$Next = $json[nextPageToken];

if($Next != null){
$NextPage = $Next;

unset($Next);
}
else{
$msg = 'Status = no NextPage' ;
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
mail("email@domain.com",'Status = no NextPage - Done',$msg);
}

}
unset($leads,$json,$Next);
}


class bList {
private $host = "Some URL";//CHANGE ME
private $clientId = "###############";//CHANGE ME
private $clientSecret = "###############";//CHANGE ME
public $listId;//id of list to retrieve leads from
public $fields = array("Time","SignUp","createdDate", etc....)

public $batchSize; //max 300 default 300
public $NextPage;
public $nextPageToken; //token returned from previous call for paging


public function getData(){

    $url = $this->host . "/rest/v1/list/" . $this->listId . "/leads.json?access_token=" . $this->getToken();
    if (isset($this->fields)){
        $url = $url . "&fields=" . $this::csvString($this->fields);
    }
    if (isset($this->batchSize)){
        $url = $url . "&batchSize=" . $this->batchSize;
    }
    if (isset($this->nextPageToken)){
        $url = $url . "&nextPageToken=" . $this->nextPageToken;
    }

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}

private function getToken(){
    $ch = curl_init($this->host . "/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . $this->clientId . "&client_secret=" . $this->clientSecret);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    $token = $response->access_token;
    return $token;
}

    private static function csvString($fields){

    $csvString = "";

    $rr= implode(",",$fields);

    $FF = str_replace(' ', '', $rr);

    $csvString = $FF;

    $csvString = rtrim($csvString,',');

    return $csvString;
    }
}

function AreUnsubscribed($G){
global $k;
global $AllLeads;
global $EmailIDs;
global $j;
global $e;
global $json;
global $Next;
$json = json_decode($G, true);

if($j == 0){

$EmailIDs[0] = $AllLeads;
$j=1;
}

if($e == 0){

for($n = 0; $n<=300; $n++){

$SORTING = $json['result'][$n]; 
if($SORTING == null){
break;
} 
else{
array_push($EmailIDs, jj($SORTING));
}
unset($SORTING);
}
$e = 1;
$k =1;

RUN();
}

if($k == 1){
Part2($json);
}
unset($EmailIDs, $json, $AllLeads);
}



function Part2($json){
global $EmailIDs;
global $g;

for($n = 0; $n<=300; $n++, $g++){ // 300 records
$SORTING = $json['result'][$n];
if($SORTING == null){
break;
} else{
$EmailIDs[$g] = array_merge((array)$EmailIDs[$g], jj($SORTING));// position
}
unset($SORTING);
}




GG($EmailIDs);
unset($EmailIDs, $json);
}

function jj($kk){
$NewArray = array();
global $AllLeads;
global $e;
    if($e == 0){
    for($b = 0; $b<270; $b++){
    if($kk[$AllLeads[$b]] == null){
    array_push($NewArray, $kk[$AllLeads[$b]]);
    }
    else{
    array_push($NewArray, '"'.$kk[$AllLeads[$b]].'"');
    }
    }
    $kk = null;

    } else{
    for($b = 270; $b<540; $b++){
    if($kk[$AllLeads[$b]] == null){
    array_push($NewArray, $kk[$AllLeads[$b]]);
    }else{
    array_push($NewArray, '"'.$kk[$AllLeads[$b]].'"');
    }
    }
    $kk = null;

    }

unset($EmailIDs, $json, $kk);
return $NewArray;
unset($NewArray);

}



function GG($val){
$datetime = date('Y-m-d');
global $EmailIDs;
global $x;
global $e;
global $g;
global $Next;
global $j;
global $json;

$handle = fopen("New" . "-Export-" . $datetime  .  ".csv", "a");


foreach($val as $value){
fputcsv($handle, (array)$value); 
}
fclose($handle);
unset($val);
//echo '<pre>';
//$vars = get_defined_vars();
//foreach($vars as $name=>$var)
//{
//  echo '<strong>' . $name . '</strong>: ' . strlen(serialize($var)) . '<br/>';
//}


$EmailIDs = array();
$Next = $json[nextPageToken];

if($Next != null){
print_r('{"Number":"'. $j . '", "Token":"' . $Next .'"}');
unset($EmailIDs, $json);
unset($GLOBALS['leads']);

 exit;

}else{
print_r('Finished');

}
}
?>
```

Comment: From what i can tell, it loops through about 100 ~115 times before stopping.

Comment: Why is `getData()` calling `getToken()` on each iteration? Oauth tokens are returned with an expiry time so you should check for that before requesting a new one. I would expect an API to stop responding to multiple token requests fom the same IP in a short space of time.